# using jsSha in XPages

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to use the jsSHA JavaScript library in an XPage.

var shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-1','HEX'); gives a runtime error : [ReferenceError] 'jsSHA' not found

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <!-- temporary redefine define.amd object  (Dojo AMD loader) -->
    <xp:script clientSide="true" type="text/javascript">
        <xp:this.contents><![CDATA[${javascript:"if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {if(define.amd.vendor =='dojotoolkit.org'){define._amd = define.amd;delete define.amd;}}";}]]></xp:this.contents>
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script src="sha.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    <xp:script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
      <!-- restore define.amd object (Dojo AMD loader) -->
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.contents><![CDATA[${javascript:"if (typeof define === 'function' && define._amd) {define.amd = define._amd; delete define._amd;}"}]]></xp:this.contents>
    </xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-1','HEX');
     return shaObj ;
}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
```

When I remove my computed field , I can see that sha.js and jquery are loaded

I got the sha file from https://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/sha.js

Answer (score 0):

You are using server side JS in your xp:text control. jsSHA is a client side JS library.

I will suggest that you use the Apache Commons Codec Java library to generate your SHA1 digest as a Hex string value:

```
DigestUtils.sha1Hex(string);
```